# UISwitch inside customFooterView needs to call a method outside of class its declared in using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates

I created a customTableViewFooter programmatically like this:

```
import UIKit

class CustomFooterView: UIView {

    let myLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: UIFontWeightMedium)
        label.textColor = UIColor.black
        label.numberOfLines = 1
        label.text = "Blah blah blah"
        label.textAlignment = .center
        return label
    }()

    let mySwitch: UISwitch = {
        let mySwitch = UISwitch()
        mySwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchChanged), for: .valueChanged)
        return mySwitch
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.setup()
        self.layout()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")

        self.setup()
        self.layout()
    }

    private func setup() {

        self.addSubview(myLabel)
        self.addSubview(mySwitch)
    }

    private func layout() {
        anonymousLabel.constrainCenterVertically()
        anonymousLabel.constrainCenterHorizontally()

        anonSwitch.constrainCenterVertically()
        anonSwitch.constrainTrailing(at: 20)
    }

    func switchChanged() {
        print("hello")
    }

}
```

Inside my class which implements the UITableView, I add this footer programmatically:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

   var footerView = CustomFooterView()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addFooter()
   }

   func addFooter() {
      tableView.tableFooterView = footerView
   }

...
}
```

At the moment, I have the method: switchChanged inside the class where I declare my UISwitch, and what I would like to do, is move this method to my ViewController, so the that the UISwitch, when selected by the user, calls a method inside my ViewController.  How would I do this?

Comment: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/quick-guide-to-swift-delegates/

Comment: Is this what you need? `footerView.mySwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(aSelector), for: .valueChanged)`

Comment: Yes it is.  Could you please put it as a solution, and I'll award you the points?  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

This should work (as already suggested in a comment)

```
footerView.mySwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(aSelector), for: .valueChanged)
```